# Bootstrap Text over Image responsive

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this markup. I am driving crazy, I really don't know how to do it. I was trying with a wrapper and an overlay but does´t work. It have to be responsive, the image and the text too. Any help please. Thanks!
[image]

Here is my markup and css:

```
<div class="franja_blanca ">
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header-img">
<img class="img-responsive" src="../header/818.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="overlay">
<div class="texto_naturopatia">
Here is my text 1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

.header-img{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
}

.header-img img {
 display:inline-block;
}



.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}


.wrapper .overlay {
    color: #333333;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .overlay {
    color: #333333;
}




.franja_blanca {
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation...

Comment: what is the actual problem ...? 
what's not being placed and where is it suppose to be placed..?

Comment: The problem is I dont have idea how to make the brown background and make it responsive for most of the divices, also the texts, they have to be responsive respect to the image. I hope can understand me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i made some coding for you,
hope it helps!
Here is the demo link:
 https://jsfiddle.net/j5rc1eyL/2/

```
<div class="position">
<div class="greybg">
    <p> HERE IS TEXT 2 HERE IS TEXT 2</p>
</div>
<div class="imagebox">
    <p>IMAGE
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    HERE IS TEXT 1 HERE IS TEXT 1
    </p>

</div>
</div>

.imagebox{
    max-width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:#0F1955;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:14px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.greybg {
    background-color: #575756;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 50px 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -155px;
}

.position {
    margin-top:70px
}
```

Comment: It looks cool! Let me try it and tell you something ok! Thanks!

Comment: :( It´s a good idea but is not working with a real image, the text 1 is not positioning above the image...

Comment: Just replace the background color of the .imagebox  to url of your actual image

Comment: Sorry its my fault, the purple/ dark blue box is an image :( sorry if I made a bad diagram. the Text 1 is above the image (the dark blue box).

Comment: No I can not do that...is complicated to explain it...the image can change, so I can not do it by css the background, it comes from an xml. I am complicating your life!!! Sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93466/discussion-between-alfonso-and-user2112420).

Comment: Yes I tried it before with an image, but you fixed the image width and height, and I would like the image resize with both texts depending on the device, if you know what I mean...